# Filtering UItableview Swift IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, filtering

I am trying to filter a UITableView based on variables that have been passed back from another VC which is a Eureka form handling the filter UI.

I would like to filter the tableview based on these two variables :

```
 var filterByPrice: Float?

 var filteredRentalTypes: Set<String>?
```

I have got the price filter working but I am having trouble filtering with the rental type. There may be a more efficient way of doing this but this is my code so far. With my current code I get an 'index out of range' crash for the rental type filter.

This is my TableViewVC:

```
class RentalTableViewVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate  {

var rentalsArray = [Rental]()
var filteredArrary = [Rental]()
var myRentals = [String]()

var filterByPrice: Float?
var filteredRentalTypes: Set<String>?


static var imageCache: NSCache<NSString, UIImage> = NSCache()


@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var hidingBarMangar: HidingNavigationBarManager?


override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "toDetailVC" {
        let destination = segue.destination as? DetailVC
        let value = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row

        if filteredArrary.count != 0 {

            destination?.emailAdress = filteredArrary[value!].email!
            destination?.bond = filteredArrary[value!].bond!
            destination?.dateAval = filteredArrary[value!].dateAval!
            destination?.pets = filteredArrary[value!].pets!
            destination?.rent = filteredArrary[value!].price!
            destination?.rentalTitle = filteredArrary[value!].title!
            destination?.imageURL = filteredArrary[value!].imageURL!
            destination?.des = filteredArrary[value!].description!
            destination?.rentalType = filteredArrary[value!].rentalType!
            destination?.streetName = filteredArrary[value!].streetName!
            destination?.city = filteredArrary[value!].city!
            destination?.postcode = filteredArrary[value!].postcode!
        } else {
            destination?.emailAdress = rentalsArray[value!].email!
            destination?.bond = rentalsArray[value!].bond!
            destination?.dateAval = rentalsArray[value!].dateAval!
            destination?.pets = rentalsArray[value!].pets!
            destination?.rent = rentalsArray[value!].price!
            destination?.rentalTitle = rentalsArray[value!].title!
            destination?.imageURL = rentalsArray[value!].imageURL!
            destination?.des = rentalsArray[value!].description!
            destination?.rentalType = rentalsArray[value!].rentalType!
            destination?.streetName = rentalsArray[value!].streetName!
            destination?.city = rentalsArray[value!].city!
            destination?.postcode = rentalsArray[value!].postcode!
        }
    }
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if filteredArrary.count != 0 {
        return filteredArrary.count
    } else {
        return rentalsArray.count
    }

}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

  var rental = rentalsArray[indexPath.row]

    if self.filteredArrary.count != 0 {
        rental = filteredArrary[indexPath.row]
    }


    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as? RentalCell {




        var rentalImage = ""

        if rental.imageURL != nil {
            rentalImage = rental.imageURL!
        }


        if let img = RentalTableViewVC.imageCache.object(forKey: rentalImage as NSString) {
            cell.configureCell(rental: rental, image: img)

            return cell
        } else {
            cell.configureCell(rental: rental, image: nil)

            return cell
        }

    } else {
        return RentalCell()
    }

}




@IBAction func backPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    hidingBarMangar?.viewWillAppear(animated)
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    hidingBarMangar?.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    hidingBarMangar?.viewWillDisappear(animated)
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()



    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

    //Firebase observer
    DataService.ds.DBrefRentals.observe(.value) { (snapshot) in

        self.rentalsArray = []
        self.filteredArrary = []

        if let snapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] {
            for snap in snapshots {
                if let dicOfRentals = snap.value as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject> {

                    let key = snap.key

                    let rental = Rental(postID: key, userData: dicOfRentals)
                    self.rentalsArray.append(rental)

                    //Placing filtered items in the filtered array
                    if self.filterByPrice != nil {
                        let priceAsFloat = (rental.price! as NSString).floatValue

                        if self.filterByPrice! >= priceAsFloat {
                            self.filteredArrary.append(rental)
                        }
                    }

                    if self.filteredRentalTypes != nil {


                        for rentals in self.filteredRentalTypes! {
                        if rental.rentalType == rentals {
                            print("******hh\(String(describing: self.filteredRentalTypes))")
                            self.filteredArrary.append(rental)
                                }

                        }
                    }


                }
            }
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }



    }
    addHidingBar()


}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    print("**********\(String(describing: filterByPrice)))")
}



func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    rentalsArray[indexPath.row].incrimentViews()

    let postViewsToFB = DataService.ds.DBrefRentals.child(rentalsArray[indexPath.row].postID!)

    postViewsToFB.child("views").setValue(rentalsArray[indexPath.row].views)

     performSegue(withIdentifier: "toDetailVC" , sender: nil)
}





func addHidingBar() {


    let extensionView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: 40))
    extensionView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    extensionView.layer.borderWidth = 1
    extensionView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 230/255, alpha: 1)
    /*let label = UILabel(frame: extensionView.frame)
    label.text = "Extension View"
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
    extensionView.addSubview(label) */

    let btn = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 15, width: 75, height: 10))
    btn.setTitle("Filter", for: .normal)
    let btnColour = UIColor(displayP3Red: 0.0, green: 122.0/255.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
    btn.setTitleColor(btnColour, for: .normal)
    btn.titleLabel?.font = headerFont
    btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(filterBtnPressed), for: .touchUpInside)

    extensionView.addSubview(btn)
    hidingBarMangar = HidingNavigationBarManager(viewController: self, scrollView: tableView)
    hidingBarMangar?.addExtensionView(extensionView)

}

@objc func filterBtnPressed() {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "toFilterVC", sender: nil)
}


}
```

Comment: Unrelated but it's unnecessarily expensive to get and force unwrap 12 times(!) the same value from an array (`filteredArrary[value!]`). That's very bad habit. And **never ever** check `.count == 0` if a collection type (or string) is empty. There is an optimized property `isEmpty`. And you are using too many question and exclamation marks.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback vadian, I will review that code.

Answer (score 0):

You may return different array in numberOfRows and their sizes may be different so check count before indexing any array as if array count != 0  doesn't mean you can index it with index path.row that may be greater then 0 ,Change this line in cellForRow

```
   if self.filteredArrary.count != 0 {
    rental = filteredArrary[indexPath.row]
}
```

to

```
  if  indexPath.row < self.filteredArrary.count  {
    rental = filteredArrary[indexPath.row]
}
```

Comment: I'm still getting an index is out of range when I select the 'entire house' filter and when selecting the others the filter does not change the tableview. Any ideas?